# Inner Class vs Static Inner Class

Tags: java

I am trying to create a linked list implementation using inner class

```
package linkedlist;

public class linkedList {

public class Node
{
    int data;
    public Node next;
    public Node(int k)
    {
        this.data = k;
        this.next=null;
    }

    public Node addToHead(int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        Node current = this;
        node.next=current;
        return node;
    }
}

public static void findn(Node head)
{
    Node previous=head;
    Node current = head;
    int i =1;
    while(current!=null)
    {


                    if (i==6)
        {
            //System.out.println(current.data);
            previous.next = current.next;
            break;
        }
                    previous=current;
                    current = current.next;
                    i++;

    }

}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    linkedList list = new linkedList();
    linkedList.Node tail = linkedList.new Node(0);
//  list.Node tail = list.Node(0);


    Node head = tail;

    for (int i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        head = head.addToHead(i);
    }

    findn(head);
    while(head!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(head.data);
        head = head.next;
    }
}
}
```

My question here in the main function i am trying to create a node using the outer class. But the syntax is throwing me an error even though i am following the right syntax. I want to know what is wrong with this statement 
     "linkedList.Node tail = linkedList.new Node(0);"

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: Why are you using a non-static inner class? Why does a `Node` care about a parent instance?

Comment: I know static inner class is the proper way. I am trying to do using an inner class. I am wondering why the error throwing up. Static inner class works fine but when i use inner class it gives me an error "linked list cannot be resolved into a variable"

Comment: If you move `findn` which is static into `Node` you will see that `linkedList` is totally useless.

Comment: _But the syntax is throwing me an error even though i am following the right syntax_... You're right. Java is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

A Node, being a non-static inner class, needs an **instance** of its enclosing class. `linkedList` is the class name. It doesn't refer to an instance of the class. So it should be

```
list.new Node()
```

It would be much clearer if you respected the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lowercase letter, and classes with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a method within class linkedList, addToTail():

```
public void addToTail(int k) {
    Node tail = new Node(k);
    //loop through all the nodes in the list and add "tail" to the end
}
```

Then you can call lst.addToTail(k) in main(), where lst would be an object of class linkedList.

BTW, it makes the code confusing to read when you begin class names with a lowercase letter.  They usually start with an uppercase letter in Java.  Calling the class LinkedList (starting with caps) is also confusing because it could be mistaken for the standard java.util.LinkedList, so perhaps you could call it LinkedList0 or something.